# Updating scaffolded controllers and views with model changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, scaffolding

For the basic functionality of my project I've been defining Entity Framework models and then using the scaffolding feature of Visual Studio to implement CRUD functionality (`Right Click` -> `Add` -> `New Scaffolded Item...`).

If I need to make a change to the model after I've done this, how do I make the scaffolded controllers and views update to the latest model changes? For example, I'm seeing the need now to add a new attribute to my model and change the data type of an existing one, but the controllers and views likely won't work after the change.

I could always just re-scaffold, but I've made some changes to the controller and views already which I don't want to lose. Is my only solution to make the changes myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename the files having your changes, scaffold again, and replace the newly-scaffolded files with your originals.

Naturally, you'll have to reconcile any domain changes that were made to the files containing your changes.